# Python program which can act like a function

Tags: python-3.x

There are two parts to my program: (Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5)

1) Python Flask Web Api which will get an image through Api for machine learning processing and will return back the response with results from machine learning python app.

2) Python program which uses machine learning to get a result based on an image.

At present, I have both the codes in the same python file. And the machine learning code is as a function processImage(image).

I would like to keep the two programs as two separate python programs. Now, the machine learning program should expose a function in such a way that I can call one function from the web api python program like **processImage(image)** for the machine learning program and should get back the result of the processing.

The reason I want this is that I want to use the machine learning process not only in flask but in other python programs as well. So, the machine learning program is running on the machine. Any other python program on the same machine should be able to get a result by just sending it an image.

Is there a way in python by which it is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand how Python modules and packages work?

Comment: HI Andrew Guy. Yeah. But if i take that as a module, every time i will have to load the whole machine learning network into the memory when required and it will be removed when the request is complete. I want the machine learning network up and ready all the time. So, it will just need to take that image as input and give out the output.

Comment: So what's wrong with making your machine learning code a module, and then loading the module into your Flask code? You shouldn't have to reload everything into memory with each request. You just call the appropriate function from the machine learning module.

Comment: the problem is that the machine learning code takes a lot of memory and if i run it as a module, then every program which runs it will create a memory footprint everytime it runs. So, if machine learning program uses 200 MB of memory, then three programs will use up 200 * 3 = 600 MB of memory. But it can be achieved with only one memory instance if i can call it as a separate program.

Comment: I did something similar with flask, perhaps you will find it useful: https://github.com/RSPB/CitizenSensor The program classifies images. You can use it n a batch mode from command line or deployed as web app.

Comment: I will check it. Thanks @LukaszTracewski